# Singleton implementation on perl6

Tags: raku

I looked at the following code on Rosetta code http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Singleton#Perl_6 
which implements Singleton in Perl6

```
class Singleton {

    has Int $.x is rw;
    # We create a lexical variable in the class block that holds our single instance.
    my Singleton $instance = Singleton.bless; # You can add initialization arguments here.
    method new {!!!} # Singleton.new dies.
    method instance { $instance; }
}

my $a=Singleton.bless(x => 1);
my $b=Singleton.bless(x=> 2);


say $a.x;
say $b.x;

#result 
# 1
# 2
```

but it seems using this implementation i can create tow instances of the same class using bless see example above ,

is there an option to prevent the implemention to only one instance of the same class ?

Comment: you could also use the type object itself as your singleton, eg `role Singleton { method new(|) { die }; method bless(|) { die }  }; class Foo does Singleton { my Int $.x }; Foo.x = 42`

Comment: To clarify Christoph's comment for other folks, a type object is an object created during compilation to represent a given type in the abstract. There's one and only one per type. The final `Foo` in Christoph's answer is treated as being a reference to the Foo type object. @Christoph I love your answer. A nice variant would be returning `self` instead of `die` from the `.new` and `.bless` methods. This way `Foo.new` returns normally rather than dying and all calls return the same type object. You'd get my vote if you turned your suggestion in to an answer.

Comment: Is this a good idea under most circumstances?  The type object is an "empty instance" which is a type of undefined object.  For example, if you pass this singleton to a routine with a signature that has `:D` specified (as some do), I would have thought it would be rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl prides itself on providing many ways to do things leaving you to pick the one that suits your tastes and the application at hand.  I say that to highlight that this is one simple but solid, hopefully self-explanatory way - I'm not putting it forward as "the best" because that depends on your circumstances.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

class Scoreboard {
  has Str $.home-team ;
  has Str $.away-team ;
  has Int $.home-score = 0 ;
  has Int $.away-score = 0 ;
  my Scoreboard $instance;

  method new(*%named) {
      return $instance //= self.bless(|%named) ;
  }

  multi method goal($team where * eq $!home-team,  Int :$points = 6) {
      $!home-score += $points
  }

  multi method goal($team where * eq $!away-team,  Int :$points = 6) {
      $!away-score += $points
  }

  method Str {
      "At this vital stage of the game " ~

      do given $!home-score <=> $!away-score {
          when More {
              "$!home-team are leading $!away-team, $!home-score points to $!away-score"
          }
          when Less {
              "$!home-team are behind $!away-team, $!home-score points to $!away-score"
          }
          default {
              "the scores are level!  $!home-score apeice!"
          }
      }
  }
}

my $home-team = "The Rabid Rabbits";
my $away-team = "The Turquoise Turtles";  # Go them turtles!

my $scoreboard = Scoreboard.new( :$home-team , :$away-team );

$scoreboard.goal($home-team, :4points) ;
say "$scoreboard";
$scoreboard.goal($away-team) ;
say "$scoreboard";
my $evil_second_scoreboard = Scoreboard.new;
$evil_second_scoreboard.goal($home-team, :2points) ;
say "$evil_second_scoreboard";
```

This produces;

```
At this vital stage of the game The Rabid Rabbits are leading The Turquoise Turtles, 4 points to 0
At this vital stage of the game The Rabid Rabbits are behind The Turquoise Turtles, 4 points to 6
At this vital stage of the game the scores are level!  6 apeice!
```

This overrides the default **new** (normally supplied by class **Mu**) and keep a reference to ourself (ie this object) in private *class* data.  For private class data, we use a lexically scoped scalar declared with **my**.  The `//` is the operator form of `.defined`.  So, on the first run, we call **bless** which allocates the object and initialize the attributes, and then assign it to `$instance`.  In subsequent calls to **new**, `$instance` is defined and is immediately returned.

If you want to prevent someone calling bless directly, you can add;

```
method bless(|) {
    nextsame unless $instance;
    fail "bless called on singleton Scoreboard"
}
```

which will ensure that only the first call will work.

Comment: what the | argument means on method bless(|) ? to accept everything as argument?

Comment: As a prefix to a parameter, '|' makes the parameter a capture and it uses up all remaining positional and named arguments that are passed (as you thought/mentioned).   As I haven't put an identifier after it, it becomes an anonymous capture - I didn't need to refer to the actual capture because I knew I'd be using __callsame__, but I did need to allow through any and all arguments because of the first call to __new__ needs to use it (that is, bless).

Comment: Thinko in previous comment.  Replace "callsame" with "nextsame".